# Copy files from SFTP to S3 (incremental upload)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, sftp

One of my customers needs us to copy files from their SFTP to our S3. They copy files into SFTP every 15 minutes, so we have files there added incrementally and then they delete files on SFTP which are older than 3 days.
So imagine we have 3000 or more files in our S3 (we need to keep them all in a S3 bucket) and then every day we have around 100 new files that need to be copied from SFTP to S3 ( all the new files which are added into SFTP).

I have a lambda function which runs every hour to handle it, but what is the most optimised way to do it:

1. Reading all SFTP file names (using ssh2-sftp-client library) and
   check which ones are not copied in S3 (using s3.headObject to check
   if file exists in S3) and then copy them. A bit expensive to iterate
   through all SFTP file name and see if they exists in S3, more than 1
   minute.
2. Reading all S3 bucket file names, reading all SFTP file names and then compare which ones are not included and then copy those. (not sure if it's reasonable performance wise)
3. or any other solutions

any better ideas?

Comment: When you list the files in SFTP, do you also receive the Upload timestamp (in addition to the filename)? Also, is there any possibility of your customer _NOT_ using SFTP and instead giving them a different way to upload their files? Is it fully automated on their end, and could they run a different script instead? Or do they do it manually?

Comment: we just have these timestamps ("modifyTime","accessTime"). no, they just have SFTP! It's fully automated on their side and automatically upload files into SFTP directory.

Comment: Any chance of them changing their "fully automated" system to a different fully automated system (eg AWS CLI)? Could you reliably use the `modifyTime` from SFTP to determine when the files were added, so you only have to copy files that were created since the last copy process ran?